# Passing multiple values for one parameter - FastReport.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, reporting

I am using FastReport.Net

How can I pass multiple values for one parameter?

Example:

```
Select * from mytable where columnX=@param1
```

Goal:

```
Select * from mytable where columnX='value1' OR columnX='value2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (columnX=@Param1 OR columnX=@Param2)
```